# Insert space at position in border line

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm displaying a horizontal line using css :

```
.horizontalLineBottom {
    border-bottom:solid #6E6A6B;
    border-width:1px;
}
```

Can I space be insterted a specific position on this line ?

So

```
______________________________________________
```

becomes

```
______________________________             ___
```

Comment: No.
You could fake it with multiple elements, though. Or border image.

Comment: You said it is vertical line but you showed example of horizontal line.

Comment: @Aspiring Aqib thanks , question updated

Comment: Depending what you need to do with this line, but it's possible and easy with CSS only with one single element. Ther are at least two solutions, one is already posted below using `:after`, `:before`.

Comment: @dfsq I have also posted fiddle. And Where is the second solution ?

Comment: @AspiringAqib posted my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution using `border-width`:

```
.line {
    width: 20px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    border-width: 0 100px 0 150px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfsq/Uttxy/1/

Comment: ahhh very good man. But limited to only that if user wants to display that line. If wants to use as div border then it is same like me e.g. Multiple elements. But still +1 for efforts.

Comment: Right, as I said for better solution we need to know what exactly OP wants to do with this lines.

Comment: IDK, why questioners go to sleep after posting questions.

Comment: Gotta leave for work in 5 minutes. Perfect time for a question on SO or an AMA on Reddit.

Answer (score 1):

`:after` or `:before` psuedo class can help you. Like in this [`Fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/nHGJL/):

```
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin:50px;
    background:yellow;
    position:relative;
}
div:after {
    content: '';
    height:60px;
    width:1px;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:-1px;
    background:yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No with border in a block (just a border for a block).

You can add a background-image, if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this directly through CSS.
I would suggest 2 solutions
1 ) you can use _ character and make it look like a line and insert space where ever you want and give color attribute through CSS.
2) Use two elements, with first element having some width and some margin-right.
The margin right will give you the required space

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `background` gradient on the element: http://jsfiddle.net/q652t/
Then you could create as many as you like

```
.line {
    margin: 10px;
    height: 1px;
    width: 400px;
    background:  -webkit-linear-gradient(
        left, gray 10%, white 10%, white 40%, 
        gray 40%, gray 60%, 
        white 60%, white 80%,
        red 80%, red 100%);
}
```

Comment: then just add in the prefixes for the other browsers

Comment: AFAIK, IE doesn't support this yet. FF only from a specific version. Cross-browser wise this is not a good solution.

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/ and what is this FF version you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly, but with a small workaround using a pseudo element. The trick is to create a small overlay with the same background color as the background underneath your element.

```
.verticalLineBottom { 
  position: relative; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #6E6A6B; 
}
.verticalLineBottom:after { 
  content: ""; 
  position: absolute; 
  right: 20px; 
  bottom: -1px; 
  width: 100px; 
  height: 1px; 
  background: #fff;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zxdS7/

Unfortunately, it does not work if the background behind your element has a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I created this code for you, this fakes the result you're looking for.

```
.stopped-line {
  /* basic styles here */

  width: 100px; /* this is mandatory */
  position: relative;
}
.stopped-line:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 70%; /* width in percentage of the line */
  content: " ";
  height: 1px; /* thickness of the line */
  background: #000; /* color of the line */
}
.stopped-line:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 80%; /* Where should the second line start? */
  display: block;
  width: 20%; /* width in percentage of the line */
  content: " ";
  height: 1px; /* thickness of the line */
  background: #000; /* color of the line */
}
```

JSBin: [click](http://jsbin.com/ekagef/1/edit)